# Unexpected identifier while trying to pass a String variable in java to JavascriptExecutor class in selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I have a String variable in Java. 
I want to pass that string variable to the javascript variable using JavascriptExecutor class in selenium

```
String eventNameFromExcel = "search results contact";
JavascriptExecutor jse  = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
List<?> al =  (List<?>) jse.executeScript( "var source = [];"+
                                     "var filterIndex=0;"+
"var eventString ="+eventNameFromExcel +";"+ //throws error unexpected identifier
             "if(dataLayer[j][\"event\"] == eventString){"+
                    "filterIndex=j;"+
                    "break;}"+
            "}");
```

Comment: You need to surround the string in quotes in JS. Currently you are generating the code `"var eventString =search results contact;"`

Comment: Expected Result: I want to pass the Java String variable to the Javascript var eventString. 
I have added the double quotes around the Javascript
"var eventString = "+eventNameFromExcel+";"